# How to create responsive image for all size in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to responsive image to support all size of android.I give a image below :-
[image]

I tried to design same layout but my layout look like:-
[image]

Can anyone tell me how i archive all this.

Comment: with the type of images he has shown in pics above, I guess 9 patch wont work

Comment: He need to measure the width of the screen and divide the items by 2 over the number of columns. Check my answer with the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an ImageView's width and height programmatically

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
imageView.getLayoutParams().height ((or width)) = display.getHeight()/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
/**
 * Created by mariano zorrilla on 11/8/15.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth() + (getMeasuredWidth() / 2));
    }
}
```

and yes... you're welcome! PS: Remove your ImageView and use this AspectRatioImageView. Use it over some Utils folder or any other place you want inside your project.

You don't need to use a gridview for this. You can use it as regular ImageView and get the same benefits.

**EDIT:** ONLY if you want to use a gridview, use this:

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/grid_images"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"/>
```

Your grid item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.your.package.utils.AspectRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_thumb_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_loading" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Image Title"
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/grid_thumb_img" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Final result:

[image: example grid]

Comment: Image are loaded from server.

Comment: I know... and this ones too (I'm getting those over Google Image API). Any, any image will scale to fit the screen like this.

Comment: I can't use grid view bcoz below of this images some TextView also.

Comment: So what... use a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout to keep the textview over or under the ImageView.

Comment: @AnandJain check my updated answer with the thing you need. You should study a bit more about gridviews and views in general.

Comment: If you need more items below the gridview (textviews, any other views), use a fixed height gridview inside a scrollview and that's it

Comment: I don't use grid view if you have any other solution than tell me.

Comment: @AnandJain do you reading me? Use a fixed height gridview so you can add any other view below the grid view. BTW, if you use my library AspectRatioImageView it would work EVEN if you don't use a gridview. Again, study more and ask less.